# PHP session ajax not sync

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

page show2.php:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["abc"]=2; 
   print $_SESSION["abc"];
   include 'import/function.php';
?>
<html>
 .............
</html>
```

page show1.php:

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["abc"]=1; 
   print $_SESSION["abc"];
   include 'import/function.php';
?>
<html>
 .............
</html>
```

I've bind an ajax_call to a btn in html that print $_SESSION["abc"]

```
session_start();
include 'import/function.php';
if(isset($_POST["data"]))
{
    print $_SESSION["abc"];
}
```

When I go in show1.php the page print 1 and ajax_call print 1.
When I go in show2.php the page print 2 but ajax_call print 1! why?

Comment: show us the ajax call, what is function.php doing?

Comment: are you sure you didn't copy `$_SESSION["abc"]=1;` into the php script that handles the post?